# When I click in a textbox, I want the page to update so the textbox moves to the top of the page on WP 8.0

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox, focus

I've got a xaml page with a huge layout and tons of textboxes etc.
I've got an issue, where if I at the bottom of the screen see a textbox, then click it to write multiple lines in it, the keyboard after 4-5 lines hides the lines being typed. I've got the textbox at a max height of 300 to fix the issue otherwise, which works just fine, if the textbox is not at the bottom of the screen when I click it.

So if i have a textbox around the middle or top of my page, and click textbox and type untill i reach the max of 300, the keyboard does not get in the way. Only when i click the textbox when it is at the bottom.

Is there any way I can make the GotFocus method do so when i get focus, it moves the page upwards, so the textbox i clicked gets moved to the top of the page. That way, I would not have this issue anymore.

Thanks.

TLDR: I want a way to make the textbox I click in to move to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
<TextBox PointerPressed="OnTextBoxPointerPressed">
    <TextBox.Projection>
       <PlaneProjection></PlaneProjection>
    </TextBox.Projection>
</TextBox
```

Then, in code behind:

```
private void OnTextBoxPointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      ((sender as TextBox).Projection as PlaneProjection).GlobalOffsetY = -300;
    }
```

I wrote it by hand so please experiment with the value of offset.